# Java throws Null exception when calling via JNI but works when calling from Java program

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am using JNI to call Java methods from .jar library from external system. My problem is that everything works fine when I write simple Java program which uses the library, but when I am executing the same code via JNI the library throws Null exception when parsing Integer from String. I am sure that there is no problem in my JNI code, because I have a newer version of the library with the same interface which works fine via JNI. But unfortunately I have to use the older version because of compatibility issues with external system.

I think that the problem is in the way how jvm.dll creates VM - I am probably missing some argument which I should pass to jvm.dll when creating VM. Does anyone know where the problem could be?

I can't post my code, but I can explain it on example:
- library version 1 contatins class Router with constructor Router(int i) - I don't have the code for this class
- library version 2 conatins same class with same constructor
- when I write simple program

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Basic
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Router = new Router(10); 
    }
}
```

it works with both libraries.

When i run the same code with newer library 2 via JNI, it works too.
But when I run the code via JNI with library 1, it crashes due to following internal exception

```
    Error message: System.Exception: JAVA Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.coda.core.types.TypeNumber.parseNumber(TypeNumber.java:403)
at com.coda.core.types.TypeInteger.parse(TypeInteger.java:123)
at com.coda.core.types.TypeInteger.parse(TypeInteger.java:137)
at com.coda.core.Options.setOption(Options.java:138)
at com.coda.core.Options.set(Options.java:85)
at com.coda.core.configuration.ConfigurationLoader.getConfiguration(ConfigurationLoader.java:144)
at com.coda.xml.Configuration.init(Configuration.java:453)
at com.coda.xml.Configuration.init(Configuration.java:370)
at com.coda.xml.router.AppServer.<init>(AppServer.java:250)
at com.coda.xml.router.Router.<init>(Router.java:122)
```

Comment: only some code might help

Comment: Show us your native code

Comment: What is the code that fails? And what does the "internal exception" say? Oh, and `jvm.dll` is (probably) not broken.

Comment: I bet it is a problem of compilation of the C code, and not Java code.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention one important thing - I am using JNI from .NET in same way as jni4net does.

Comment: I guess the new lib does a null-check of the params, while the older one does not? Ah, no wait. Nevermind ...

Comment: I will try to write the whole C# code in C and then we will see.

Comment: Fildor - that's not a problem. The older library works fine when using from simple java program with same arguments.

Comment: It works fine when running via JNI from C++. There has to be some problem in my .NET code. I am trying everything in 64-bit mode

Comment: I have prepared the easiest .NET JNI wrapper as possible and it works too, so I am now looking for the differences. Probably working directory of whole app is problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I had really mistake in parameters for JVM. The older library requires another jar library what I didn't knew. So I have added the library to class path and it works fine know. Really stupid exception with nothing saying message turned me to look for a problem in wrong way.

Thanks everybody for comments